# Using specific tiles on ionic platform

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create a mobile app in android / IOS and i am thinking to use ionic.

Does ionic has the ability to present my specific tiles on a map at offline ?

Should i use ionic 3, or previous version ?

Answer (score 0):

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) for example provides a plugin to do so.

> TileLayer.Cordova 
>   For use with Cordova/Phonegap, adds tile caching onto local device storage, switching between offline and online mode.

I don't see a big reason to use previous version of Ionic. You could even try Ionic 4